# using $watch on a table cell

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to update trigger an update based on the value of a input box in a table cell changing. The table is bulit using ng-repeat against the results of a $resource call.

Key is that I need to update 2 different values for each time it's changed. 1 is another cell inside the same table row, the second is outside of the table itself. This seems to prevent the use of a specific controller at the ng-repeat level.

I created this plunkr to try to help. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/773WhoUvWoUZ40AfuzMO?p=preview

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('ItemCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.user_votes = 100;
  $scope.items = [
      {item: "Foo1", description: "Really Fancy Foo", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
      {item: "Foo2", description: "Boring Foo", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
      {item: "Widget 1", description: "Base widget 1", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
      {item: "Big Widget", description: "Humongous Widget", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
      {item: "FooBar", description: "FooBar in Gold", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0}
  ];


     // This doesn't work, but I am not sure why.
     $scope.$watch('item.my_votes', function(newVal, oldVal){
       $scope.user_votes = $scope.user_votes - newVal.my_votes;
       newVal.total_votes = newVal.total_votes + newVal.my_votes;
     });
});
```

html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.1.5">       </script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
<div>You have {{ user_votes }} votes remaining</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>My Votes</th>
      <th>Total Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>{{ item.item }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
      <td><input name="votes" ng-model="item.my_votes"/></td>
      <td>{{ item.total_votes }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button ng-click="saveForm">Cast Votes</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no single item on your controller scope since ng-repeat creates its own isolated scope ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)). That's why nothing is happening after you change your model. You can take different approaches to achieve live-reloading in this case. You can either perform deep watch on your items array ($scope.$watchCollection) or you can use ng-change which works in combination with ng-model like this:

HTML

```
<div>You have {{ user.left }} votes remaining</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>My Votes</th>
      <th>Total Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>{{ item.item }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
      <td><input name="votes" type='number' ng-model="item.my_votes" ng-change='recalc()'></td>
      <td>{{ item.total_votes + item.my_votes }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button ng-click="saveForm">Cast Votes</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.user = {
  base: 100,
  left: 100
}

$scope.items = [
  {item: "Foo1", description: "Really Fancy Foo", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
  {item: "Foo2", description: "Boring Foo", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
  {item: "Widget 1", description: "Base widget 1", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
  {item: "Big Widget", description: "Humongous Widget", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0},
  {item: "FooBar", description: "FooBar in Gold", total_votes: 0, my_votes: 0}
];

$scope.recalc = function() {
  $scope.user.left = $scope.user.base;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    $scope.user.left -= ($scope.items[i].total_votes + $scope.items[i].my_votes);
  }
}
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uHME8xE7aLDLDf3VT4cg?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ng-change here? And put what you have in your watch in a function that will get called on ng-change.

```
<td><input name="votes" ng-model="item.my_votes" ng-change="watchFunction(item.my_votes, {{item.my_votes}})"/></td>
```

where the first argument is the new value, and the second one is the old value. (if you need old value, at all)